# Yii2 How to change route from foo-bar to foo_bar

Tags: routes, yii2

I've the controller function named like `actionFooBar()`

I can access with `index.php?r=class/foo-bar`

If I want to change to available with url like `index.php?r=class/foo_bar`

How can I do this ?

Comment: Yes, this is work, Thank :)

Answer (score 2):

foo-bar actually the action is actionFooBar

to change it to foo_bar make it actionFoo_bar

and if you use pretty url add route rules

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

to accept special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I can done this by change function name to `actionFoo_bar()`

Now I can access to `index.php?r=class/foo_bar`

Does not sure that their are another solution or not?

Comment: No, it looks like a hack. Use `urlManager` `rules` to achieve that.